# repetitive code for bar chart visializations

Tags: r

I am visualizing data from wine with bar charts. how do I get rid of repetitive code?

```
qplot(x = pH, data = wineData)
qplot(x = sulphates, data = wineData)
qplot(x = density, data = wineData)
qplot(x = chlorides, data = wineData)
qplot(x = citric.acid, data = wineData)
qplot(x = fixed.acidity, data = wineData)
qplot(log10(x = residual.sugar), data = wineData)
qplot(x = volatile.acidity, data = wineData)
```

result should be the same but without as much code and not repeating "data=winedata" and "qplot"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggplot2` and a simple for loop:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_list <- list()

for (i in names(wineData)){
  plt <- ggplot(wineData) +
    geom_bar(aes_string(i))
  plot_list[[i]] <- plt
}
```

Comment: You can avoid the explicit `for` if you use `lapply` or `purrr::map`; e.g. `plot_list <- map(names(wineData), ~qplot(x = .x, data = wineData))` which makes this an one-liner.

Comment: but would that give the same result? one of them is Log and i do not want all names in wineData. only the ones that are above

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks! That's really clean.

Comment: @Goldaaron18 If you only want the ones you mentioned, just store the names in a vector `cols <- c("pH", "sulphates", "density", "chlorides", "citric.acid", "fixed.acidity", "residual.sugar", "volatile.acidity")` and change the loop to `for (i in cols){}`. I don't know what you mean by 'one of them is Log'.

Comment: I am transforming the data for residual.sugar by applying the log function to get a better distribution. so would that be done separately?